How I can define and execute the s3Upload lane properly
After setup Adhoc file export I did executale s3Upload file using this command
  lane :s3Upload do
    sh("ls")
    sh("./s3_upload.sh")
  end

But This is not execute s3Upload file. It just represent output Like this
INFO [2024-07-08 10:19:51.55]: ------------------------------
INFO [2024-07-08 10:19:51.55]: --- Step: default_platform ---
INFO [2024-07-08 10:19:51.55]: ------------------------------
INFO [2024-07-08 10:19:51.55]: Driving the lane 'ios s3Upload' 
INFO [2024-07-08 10:19:51.55]: ----------------
INFO [2024-07-08 10:19:51.55]: --- Step: ls ---
INFO [2024-07-08 10:19:51.55]: ----------------
INFO [2024-07-08 10:19:51.55]: $ ls
INFO [2024-07-08 10:19:51.56]: ▸ Fastfile
INFO [2024-07-08 10:19:51.56]: ▸ README.md
INFO [2024-07-08 10:19:51.56]: ▸ report.xml
INFO [2024-07-08 10:19:51.56]: ▸ s3_upload.sh
INFO [2024-07-08 10:19:51.56]: ----------------------------
INFO [2024-07-08 10:19:51.56]: --- Step: ./s3_upload.sh ---
INFO [2024-07-08 10:19:51.56]: ----------------------------
INFO [2024-07-08 10:19:51.56]: $ ./s3_upload.sh

I am expecting to resolve this issue using fastlane How can I execute the s3Upload lane properly
